# AWS WAF: How to make custom response code with managed rules for block actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

AWS added the option to return custom status code, instead of the default 403.

From here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/customize-requests-and-responses-with-aws-waf/ I added custom status for my own rules, but it seems like for managed rules (e.g - Cyber Security Cloud Managed Rules), there is no way to change the action and status.

Can someone help here please?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use labels for this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-labels.html

Write a custom rule to act on the labels and then have a custom response on the custom rule you create.

[Use custom responses to change the default block action for a managed rule group](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-customize-behavior-of-aws-managed-rules-for-aws-waf/)

Comment: Thanks, it seems like there are labels only for AWS managed rules and not for another managed rules as Cyber Security Cloud. Do you know if/how we can get labels also for them?