How to use AWS WAF managed rules custom response through action overrides?
Why are AWS WAF managed rules custom response through action overrides not working?
This is explicitely documented here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-managedrulegroupstatement.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-managedrulegroupstatement-ruleactionoverrides
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-blockaction.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-rule-group-override-options.html

This is NOT working and I still see the default AWS WAF 403 response intead of my custom plain text error:
Resources:
  Waf:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      Scope: CLOUDFRONT
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {} # Allow for requests that don't match any rules
      CustomResponseBodies:
        SecurityViolationError:
          ContentType: TEXT_PLAIN
          Content: Request blocked due to security concerns as it was detected as malicious.
      Rules:
        - Priority: 0
          Name: BlockSqlInjection
          OverrideAction:
            None: {}
          Statement:
            ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
              VendorName: AWS
              Name: AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet
              Version: Version_2.0
              RuleActionOverrides:
                - Name: SQLi_QUERYARGUMENTS
                  ActionToUse:
                    Block:
                      CustomResponse:
                        ResponseCode: 403
                        CustomResponseBodyKey: SecurityViolationError
                - Name: SQLi_BODY
                  ActionToUse:
                    Block:
                      CustomResponse:
                        ResponseCode: 403
                        CustomResponseBodyKey: SecurityViolationError
                - Name: SQLi_COOKIE
                  ActionToUse:
                    Block:
                      CustomResponse:
                        ResponseCode: 403
                        CustomResponseBodyKey: SecurityViolationError
                - Name: SQLiExtendedPatterns_QUERYARGUMENTS
                  ActionToUse:
                    Block:
                      CustomResponse:
                        ResponseCode: 403
                        CustomResponseBodyKey: SecurityViolationError
                - Name: SQLiExtendedPatterns_BODY
                  ActionToUse:
                    Block:
                      CustomResponse:
                        ResponseCode: 403
                        CustomResponseBodyKey: SecurityViolationError

I do know that custom response for managed rules is working with label matching:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/waf-managed-rules
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72261408/1480391

This is working,  I can see my custom plain text error:
Resources:
  Waf:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      Scope: CLOUDFRONT
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {} # Allow for requests that don't match any rules
      CustomResponseBodies:
        SecurityViolationError:
          ContentType: TEXT_PLAIN
          Content: Request blocked due to security concerns as it was detected as malicious.
      Rules:
        - Priority: 0
          Name: LabelSqlInjection
          OverrideAction:
            Count: {}
          Statement:
            ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
              VendorName: AWS
              Name: AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet
              Version: Version_2.0
          - Priority: 1
            Name: BlockSecurityViolationError
            Statement:
              LabelMatchStatement:
                Scope: NAMESPACE
                Key: "awswaf:managed:aws:sql-database:"
            Action:
              Block:
                CustomResponse:
                  ResponseCode: 403
                  CustomResponseBodyKey: SecurityViolationError

But this requires having an extra rule introducing extra costs.
Am I missing something? Are custom responses achievable with managed rule group action override?
Is there something missing in AWS documentation?

You cant change the custom response for managed rules. All you can change is the action type. If you dig deeper into the cloud formation docs for managed rules, you'll see that RuleActionsOverides only allows you to change ActionToUse. There is no CustomResponse field like you have in your template.
As you mentioned, currently the only way to achieve a custom response, is to set a custom rule on labels.
